# Null point exception while trying to use images in an adapter?

Tags: android

i have a class ArtistResourceImageAdapter which extends ArtistCoverFlowAdapter
 i am getting a null point exception 
in one of the strings(which is supposed to hold the path of the images)
the string is "res"
when i put a check in the constructor it doesn't appear to be null(i checked using logcat)
but it seems to be null in this method

```
@override 
protected Bitmap createBitmap(  int position) {
 if(res[position]==null)
        ..........
..............
..................          
}
```

Now the method createBitmap has been overridden in ArtistResourceImageAdapter,and was declared in the class ArtistCoverFlowAdapter.

The code for ArtistResourceImageAdapter is (last method(createBitmap) in this code is where i am getting a null point exception for the string  )

```
package source.justanothermusicplayer.coverflw;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import source.justanothermusicplayer.R;
import source.justanothermusicplayer.R.drawable;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;

/**
 * This class is an adapter that provides images from a fixed set of resource
 * ids. Bitmaps and ImageViews are kept as weak references so that they can be
 * cleared by garbage collection when not needed.
 * 
 */
public class ArtistResourceImageAdapter extends ArtistCoverFlowAdapter {

    /** The Constant TAG. */
    private static final String TAG = ArtistResourceImageAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    float ht_px;float wt_px;
    /** The Constant DEFAULT_LIST_SIZE. */
    private static final int DEFAULT_LIST_SIZE = 40;

    /** The Constant IMAGE_RESOURCE_IDS. */
    private static final List<Integer> IMAGE_RESOURCE_IDS = new ArrayList<Integer>(DEFAULT_LIST_SIZE);

    /** The Constant DEFAULT_RESOURCE_LIST. */
  String[] res=new String[20];
    /** The bitmap map. */
    private final Map<Integer, WeakReference<Bitmap>> bitmapMap = new HashMap<Integer, WeakReference<Bitmap>>();

    private final Context context;

    /**
     * Creates the adapter with default set of resource images.
     * 
     * @param context
     *            context
     */

    public ArtistResourceImageAdapter(final Context context,String [] resources) { 
        super();
        this.context = context;
      ht_px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 130,context. getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
      wt_px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 115,context. getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

           setResources(resources);
    }



    public final synchronized void setResources(String[] resources) {
        IMAGE_RESOURCE_IDS.clear();res=resources;
            for ( int Id =1; Id<=resources.length;Id++) {
            IMAGE_RESOURCE_IDS.add(Id);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
   }

    /**
     * Replaces resources with those specified.
     * 
     * @param resourceIds
     *            array of ids of resources.
     */

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getCount()
     */
    @Override
    public synchronized int getCount() {
        return IMAGE_RESOURCE_IDS.size();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see pl.polidea.coverflow.AbstractCoverFlowImageAdapter#createBitmap(int)
     */
    @Override
    protected Bitmap createBitmap(  int position) {
        Log.v(TAG, "creating item " + position);
        String url=new String();
        if(res[position]==null)
            Log.i("holalala  jhingallaa ", "res[position] is null");
        url=res[position];
        Bitmap  b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url);
         b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) ht_px, (int) wt_px, true);
        bitmapMap.put(position, new WeakReference<Bitmap>(b));
        return b;
    }


}
```

the logcat:

```
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at source.justanothermusicplayer.coverflw.ArtistResourceImageAdapter.createBitmap(ArtistResourceImageAdapter.java:99)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at source.justanothermusicplayer.coverflw.ArtistCoverFlowAdapter.getItem(ArtistCoverFlowAdapter.java:73)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at source.justanothermusicplayer.coverflw.ArtistReflectingAdapter.createBitmap(ArtistReflectingAdapter.java:79)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at source.justanothermusicplayer.coverflw.ArtistCoverFlowAdapter.getItem(ArtistCoverFlowAdapter.java:73)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at source.justanothermusicplayer.coverflw.ArtistReflectingAdapter.createBitmap(ArtistReflectingAdapter.java:79)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at source.justanothermusicplayer.coverflw.ArtistCoverFlowAdapter.getItem(ArtistCoverFlowAdapter.java:73)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at source.justanothermusicplayer.coverflw.ArtistCoverFlowAdapter.getView(ArtistCoverFlowAdapter.java:117)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at source.justanothermusicplayer.coverflw.ArtistCoverFlowAdapter.getView(ArtistCoverFlowAdapter.java:1)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:193)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15401)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4950)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:703)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:578)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15401)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4950)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:314)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15401)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:855)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:578)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15401)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4950)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:314)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2154)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15401)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1856)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1279)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1002)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4294)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:643)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4803)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
12-12 14:16:58.876: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: line no 99 is  b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) ht_px, (int) wt_px, true);
      

in the last method

Comment: ok i think i got it, first you have defined res to hold maximum of 20 itmes, check the value of position am sure you are trying to access index 20+, thats why you are receiveing this error

Comment: @Techfist nope i don't think so....even if i increase its size it didn't help

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava where is res array populated?

Comment: @Techfist i have edited the comment above..i pointed out the wrong line no

Comment: createScaledBitmap will only throw NPE it supplied bitmap is null, that can only be derived from your file itself being null, which will lead toward res[position] returning null, which I said you earlier you are trying to access wrong index, even you said you increased array size, but that index doesnt hold correct reference to a file, so check that.

Comment: @Raghunandan it is populated using a mediastore in a different activity...i thought that it might be null there  but it isn't .....
and by the way...the res string is not null at one point(in the method "setResources"the first method after constructor  )  in this code,but seems to be null at another point (the last method )..

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava where is res populates in `ArtistResourceImageAdapter` ? here `res=resources` right? and where is `createBitmap` caclled

Comment: @Raghunandan it is being called in ArtistCoverFlowAdapter
and i have setted up ArtistCoverFlowAdapter by 
 ArtistCoverFlowAdapter coverImageAdapter;
               coverImageAdapter = new ArtistReflectingAdapter(new ArtistResourceImageAdapter(this,img));
               //coverImageAdapter = new ArtistResourceImageAdapter(this,img);
                  
            mCoverFlow.setAdapter(coverImageAdapter);

Comment: @Raghunandan ..........?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's look  like in case of res[position] returnns null, you are continuing to process the rest of the code and I believe that is what giving you null pointer as you are using that null value to process the rest of the logic.
Try to add a bracket for the the condition check and return null. Method which is using createBitmap need to handle null bitmap as it is not available.

```
protected Bitmap createBitmap(  int position) {
    Log.v(TAG, "creating item " + position);
    String url=new String();
    if(res[position]==null) {
        Log.i("holalala  jhingallaa ", "res[position] is null");
        return null;
    }
    url=res[position];
    File f=new File(url);
    Bitmap  b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url);
    b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) ht_px, (int) wt_px, true);
    bitmapMap.put(position, new WeakReference<Bitmap>(b));
    return b;
}
```